# Can a data disk (say D drive) be added through ARM Teamplate while creating a VM in Azure if the image has only OS Disk (C drive)?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, azure-vm

I am using an image (Windows & Linux) to create VMs in Azure through ARM template. The image has only OS Disk (C Drive). I need Data disk also (say D drive). Can I create data disk through ARM Template while creating the VM using the image with only C drive ? I need this for Windows as well as Linux. If so, is there any reference ?

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/using-managed-disks-template-deployments) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot, will it work the same way for Linux VMs as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, most image only has the OS disk, it's the same as your image. And to create a VM with a data disk via the ARM template, you just need to add the [`dataDisks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2020-06-01/virtualmachines#datadisk-object) block in the [VM resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2020-06-01/virtualmachines). It's a list, you can add one or more disks, and then Azure will create it or them for you. It's not complex.

And on the other hand, the D drive usually is the [temporary disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/managed-disks-overview?toc=/azure/virtual-machines/linux/toc.json&bc=/azure/virtual-machines/linux/breadcrumb/toc.json#disk-roles). So in fact, the data disk should be the E drive or after E.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Charles. Will it work the same way for Linux VMs as well ?

Comment: @Chaitanya Yes, it works for all the VMs. By the way, if it solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: I am facing issue when I am trying to add additional datadisks when the image already has one data disk. I get error message- 


"Deployment template validation failed: 'Can not add property dataDisks to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object."

Comment: can you help with the above scenario

Comment: @Chaitanya Share your ARM template, please.

Comment: @Chaitanya Do you still work on this issue? I didn't see any updates serial days.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was on break and not working. Sharing the template will be tough because of compliance issues. Let me see a workaround for that. Meanwhile can you suggest any other changes or is it allowed to have additional datadisks while creating VM when the image used already has one data disk ?

Comment: @Chaitanya You ask about the image only have OS disk, so I provide the solution in this answer. If it works for this issue, you can accept it. And I see you ask post another question about it, I will provide a solution to that question, not here.